# Cognos like cubes

Tags: java, cube, cognos

What are the various options to have a cube designer in Java other than Cognos?
Basically I need to see a multi-dimensional cube and the user must be able to select the columns to filter by.

Comment: `multi dimensional cube` - isn't the definition of a cube to be 3-dimensional? (Having more dimensions would result in a hyper-cube and you wouldn't be able to display that). :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to take a look at [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/)

It's a very comprehensive BI solution, open source, Java based.

There's an online demo of some of the features: http://demo.pentaho.com

There is "some assembly required" to the extent that it is more of a toolkit for building BI solutions than an "out of the box" product. But it is very capable and mature, probably the best solution available if you don't want to buy an expensive proprietary tool like Cognos.